# How to loop through a JSON string inside an array for getting particular column

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, curl

I am trying to get the data from an API and for that I am using php curl.

My API data looks like this:

```
{"COLUMNS":["COCD","CONAME","KINDOFACCOUNT","ACCOUNTCODE","ACCOUNTNAME","TELNO","FAX","ADDR","OPENINGBALANCE","DR_AMT","CR_AMT","VOUCHERDATE","SETTLEMENT_NO","CTRCODE","CTRNAME","TRANS_TYPE","VOUCHERNO","NARRATION","BILLNO","CHQNO","EXPECTED_DATE","TRADING_COCD","PANNO","EMAIL","MANUALVNO","BOOKTYPECODE","BILL_DATE","MKT_TYPE","GROUPCODE","BRSFLAG","SETL_PAYINDATE","LAST2SETL","ACCOUNTCODE1","GATEWAYID","PUNCH_TIME","TRANS_TYPE1"],"DATA":[["MCX","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["MCX","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["NSE_FNO","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["NSE_FNO","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["NSE_FNO","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","0.00","500.00","","0","0","","OP","0","OPENING BALANCE","0","0","","NSE_FNO","","","0","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["MCX","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","0.00","1192.77","","0","0","","OP","0","OPENING BALANCE","0","0","","MCX","","","0","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""]]}
```

I am able to fetch the array i.e all COLUMNS name but when I am trying to fetch only COCD column it said : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://myapi.cfm';
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: application/json",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json"
       ),));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
      $characters = json_decode($response, true);
      print_r ($characters['COLUMNS']);

      foreach ($characters as $character) {
         print_r ($character->CONAME . '<br>');
          }
       }
?>
```

Please help, I am searching for the answer for long time now.

Comment: Looks like you've got it backwards, your container is an object, so `$characters->COLUMNS` which is in turn an array... so `$characters->COLUMNS[1]` or `$character[1]` in the loop is `CONAME`.

Comment: You are explicitly telling `json_decode()` to get you an associative array, so you will not have any objects, only nested arrays. And `CONAME` is a value in only one of your elements, not a key.

Comment: @CD001 Same error when I am using $characters->COLUMNS['CONAME'] and Notice: Undefined index: CONAME when I am using $character['CONAME'] in loop

Comment: You should pretty-print / `var_dump()` the decoded array and you will see clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Please use print_r ($character->CONAME . '<br>'); to "echo $character[0];" in foreach loop.
Please this cod use :- foreach ($characters as $character) {
  //echo '<pre>'; print_r($character);
  echo $character[0];
  //echo $character[0];
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach to translating this data...

```
// Standard JSON decode, no `true` second parameter
$source = json_decode('{"COLUMNS":["COCD","CONAME","KINDOFACCOUNT","ACCOUNTCODE","ACCOUNTNAME","TELNO","FAX","ADDR","OPENINGBALANCE","DR_AMT","CR_AMT","VOUCHERDATE","SETTLEMENT_NO","CTRCODE","CTRNAME","TRANS_TYPE","VOUCHERNO","NARRATION","BILLNO","CHQNO","EXPECTED_DATE","TRADING_COCD","PANNO","EMAIL","MANUALVNO","BOOKTYPECODE","BILL_DATE","MKT_TYPE","GROUPCODE","BRSFLAG","SETL_PAYINDATE","LAST2SETL","ACCOUNTCODE1","GATEWAYID","PUNCH_TIME","TRANS_TYPE1"],"DATA":[["MCX","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["MCX","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["NSE_FNO","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["NSE_FNO","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["NSE_FNO","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","0.00","500.00","","0","0","","OP","0","OPENING BALANCE","0","0","","NSE_FNO","","","0","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""],["MCX","","PARTY","TT3405","ANTHONIRAJ P","","","","0","0.00","1192.77","","0","0","","OP","0","OPENING BALANCE","0","0","","MCX","","","0","3","","","","","","","TT3405","","",""]]}');

// Loop over each row and turn it into assoc array
foreach( $source->DATA as &$data )
{
  $data = array_combine( $source->COLUMNS, $data );
}

// Get just the COCD column
print_R( array_column( $source->DATA, 'COCD' ) );

//  Array
//  (
//    [0] => MCX
//    [1] => MCX
//    [2] => NSE_FNO
//    [3] => NSE_FNO
//    [4] => NSE_FNO
//    [5] => MCX
//  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. the response is like : Array ( [0] => MCX [1] => MCX [2] => NSE_FNO [3] => NSE_FNO [4] => NSE_FNO [5] => MCX ) .. what to do to hide the word Array and indexes in front and I will  accept this answer

Comment: you can just do `$COCD = array_column( $source->DATA, 'COCD' );` and then use `$COCD` as you wish. `print_r` is just for debugging/demonstration.

Comment: so I did:
$source = json_decode($response);
// Loop over each row and turn it into assoc array
foreach( $source->DATA as &$data )
{
  $data = array_combine( $source->COLUMNS, $data );
}
// Get just the COCD column
$COCD = array_column( $source->DATA, 'COCD' );
echo $COCD; but error: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: You can't just `echo $COCD;` because its an array, how do you want to use that data? `echo implode(',',$COCD);` would work because its a string then...

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help, I have already accepted your answer. One last question plss what if I want to show only last available data in that column like here for CR_AMT is 1192.77

Comment: `array_column( $source->DATA, 'CR_AMT' )` is simply picking all the "CR_AMT" values out of the array translation I wrote. you could then do `max( array_column( $source->DATA, 'CR_AMT' ) )` etc

Comment: Yes, I got that, but here I only want to print 1192.77 value as some are null and some are of no use

Comment: Describe to me how you expect to select `1192.77`, is it the last row? is it the largest row? `$CR_AMT=array_column($source->DATA,'CR_AMT'); echo end($CR_AMT);` or even `echo end($source->DATA)['CR_AMT'];` to print the last value, and as I posted above `max(array_column($source->DATA,'CR_AMT'))` to get the largest single value out of that column.